# Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-support-library, android-styles

I use the android.support library for my project, I have developed my app using android 4.4 and everything works good but my problem comes when I try to run the application in a device with Android Lollipop.

When it loads the Activity with the Toolbar, the application stops and returns this error.

**Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar**

I have found the same problem on the internet but I haven't found the solution in the answers.

This is my styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_primary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color</item>
</style>
```

Here is my styles.xml (v22)

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_primary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent_color</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

To define the toolbar in .xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mitoolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" />
```

And in my MainActivty I just include that toolbar:

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

And finally the header of my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //Here stops my application
}
```

Heres the logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fitness.dullmonkey.keepingfit/com.fitness.dullmonkey.keepingfit.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2581)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2656)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1512)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5691)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:892)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.fitness.dullmonkey.keepingfit.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6142)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1115)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2528)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2656)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1512)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5691)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:892)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.fitness.dullmonkey.keepingfit.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6142)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1115)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2528)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2656)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1512)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5691)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 216
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:569)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4084)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:524)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:520)
            at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:195)
            at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:191)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:892)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.fitness.dullmonkey.keepingfit.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6142)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1115)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2528)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2656)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1512)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5691)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: check the manifest file

Comment: Post the logcat.also the appcompat requires an appcompat theme

Comment: Logcat posted @GabrieleMariotti.

Comment: Edited: Would it help if, under your styles.xml (v22), you modify the parent theme to use <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"> (i.e. using the support library version)?

Comment: Thank you very much @headuck, now it works great!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The cause of the error is that, in the toolbar xml, the `?attr` prefix refers to attributes in support library themes.  On the other hand, under v22 of `style.xml` above, the system theme `android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar` instead of a support library theme is used.  The inflater therefore cannot resolve attributes of the support library such as `?attr/actionBarSize`.

Using the support library theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` in style.xml (regardless of version) addresses the issue.

Answer (score 0):

in my case the same error but no symptoms of ?attr in android axml file

it looks like a compatibility issue of Xamarin.Appcombat (I found somewhere in web)

try to deploy the same project into lower Android API

in my case Android simulator API 21 had the error above , but another simulator with Android API 18 had no problem at all